# Rails 6.0 validate password presence on create and update for one type of user but only update for another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, passwords, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `User` model with the following attributes:

```
 id: integer
 username: string
 email: string
 password_hash: string
 password_salt: string
 account_type: string
 ...
```

My goal is to validate a user's password on create and update.

When a user with `account_type: 'a'` gets created or updated I want to run `validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true`.

When a user with `account_type: 'b'` gets updated I want to validate the `password` and `password_confirmation` presence as true, but **NOT** when the user gets created.

If more code or a clearer explanation would help, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so for user account_type b no validation whatsoever should happen (At least regarding the presence?)

Comment: I want to validate the password presence for users with account_type b but only on update, not on create.

Comment: "Sometimes it will make sense to validate an object only when a given predicate is satisfied. You can do that by using the :if and :unless options, which can take a symbol, a Proc or an Array. You may use the :if option when you want to specify when the validation should happen. If you want to specify when the validation should not happen, then you may use the :unless option." https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true, unless: -> { |user| user.account_type == 'b' && user.new_record? }
```

Comment: Instead of `user.new_record?` you can use  `on: :update` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Comment: @max if he wants to use on: :update he will lose the :create case right? He won't be able to use a one liner at least

Comment: Ah you're correct. It would only apply the validations on update.

Comment: @Joel_Blum that did indeed work! Thanks for the help to the both of you.